# Call a function from another page in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to call some public method of the page from another page

Here is my code

```
   public class FirstPage : Page
   {
   public string Connect()
   {
    // method code here
   }
   // etc...
   }
```

It gives an error while calling this method from another page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the method is common to both pages then consider using a base class for the page that inherits from Page. The method can go there.

```
public YourPage: BaseClass
{
     public void MyMethod()
     {
         base.BaseMethod();
     }
}

public BaseClass: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //.. your shared method goes here
    protected BaseMethod()
    {
         //.. logic here
    }
}
```

This makes sense if your pages share the same functional area e.g. they are all about order processing

Answer (score 2):

It's not great practice. If both pages want to share the method, then you can put them in another class/class library, and instantiate and call that from both pages.

The approach you would use is determined by the nature of the method; consider the context. If we are in the context of the `Page` then it may be best to consider that the functionality here should be related to activities that should take place in a Page - that is, presentation (rendering of the GUI).

If the functionality is related to presentation then consider using either a shared class or a [common base class](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/01/generic-base-classes-in-aspnet.html).

In the question, the method to be shared is `Connect` - if this is connecting to a service or database for data, then consider encapsulating this code as an extra library; this library can then be *reused* across multiple projects (regardless of the style of display), and the logic would be *independent* of the display; for example:

```
public partial class MyCodeBehindCS : System.Web.UI.Page
{     
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MyNamespace.MyCustomClass myClass = new MyNamespace.MyCustomClass();
        myClass.Connect();
        var myResult = myClass.DoSomething();

    }
}
```

You can then do whatever you want with myResult.

Comment: can u give a simple example for it?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is wrong 100%. Please, re-factor your code and find other way to realize your task.

What you can do in order to share some method between multiple pages is to implement custom Page class

```
public class FirstPage : YourCustomPageClass
   {
   public string A()
   {
       return this.YourCUstomPageCLassMethod();
   }
   // etc...
   }



public class SecondPage : YourCustomPageClass
   {
   public string B()
   {
    return this.YourCUstomPageCLassMethod();
   }
   // etc...
   }
```

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178138.aspx) and [here](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/56_Using_Custom_BasePage_Class_in_ASPNet.aspx)

Comment: Since .NET gives you that opportunity to do that; how come you can judge a working code as 100% wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you want to calculate the average of an array of values.

Create a blank code page. I'll call it mu.cs. Here is the code:

```
using System;
namespace mu
{
    public static class mu
    {
        public static double themean(double[] thearray, int n)
        {
            double mysum = 0;
            double mymu = 0;
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                mysum += thearray[i];
            mymu = mysum/n;

            return mymu;
        }
    }
)
```

Suppose your other page is test.cshtml.cs and your array has 4 values.

Then, in the appropriate section, you can call your function.

```
public class testModel : PageModel
{
    public int i = 0;
    public int n = 4;
    public double mymean = 0;
    public double[] myarray = new double[n];
 
    public void OnGet()
    {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            myarray[i] = i;
        mymean = mu.mu.themean(myarray, n);
    }
}
```

In calling the function, the first mu refers to the namespace and the second mu refers to the class.

Answer (score -2):

In the second Page, enter the code that you can access the first Page functions

```
<%@ Reference Page="~/page1.aspx" %>
```

> Now you can call functions to read the first Page

```
 page1.func1();
```

---

or

```
page1 a=new page1();
a.func1();
```